# Проверка даты

Tags: дата, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть функция валидации, в ней следующее выражение

```
var valid = /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/;
return valid.test(value);
```

В описании регулярных выражений нашел логические операторы больше, меньше; пытюсь добавить к существующему коду "но он не работает" &copy; Кеп

```
valid = /^(0<\d{2}<32)-(0<\d{2}<13)-(1000<\d{4}<3000)/;
```

Формат даты dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Если не секрет, где вы такое нашли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет

```
valid = /^[0-3][0-9]-[0|1][0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2}/
```

Comment: вообще неправильно, дни у вас учитываются до 39 включительно, месяц до 19 а год только 1900-2099, по мне так проще дату парсить через `split`

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidDate(val)
{
  var val_r = val.split("-");
  var curDate = new Date(val_r[2], val_r[1], val_r[0]);
  return (
    curDate.getFullYear() == val_r[2]
    && curDate.getMonth() == val_r[1]
    && curDate.getDate() == val_r[0]
  );
}
```

Через регэкспы решение данной задачи стремится к невозможности.

Comment: Возможность все же есть, но она бессмысленна абсолютно. Типа ([0]1|[0]2|[0]3...)| и т.д. для каждого месяца, для високосных годов еще и по февралю :)

Comment: Хотел было, прикола ради, написать этот "длиннннннющий" регэксп, но не стал удручать ни себя, ни других :)